# What was the time span over which the events in Half Life took place?

Tags: video-games, half-life, time

What was the time it took Gordon to get from the beginning of the story (anomalous materials facility of Black Mesa) to the Nihilanth? I believe he arrived in the morning but I don't recall walking around outside during night. Was it just another *day* at the office?

Comment: See http://qntm.org/hl

Comment: @b_jonas: Looks interesting. Why not extending your comment into a proper answer?

Comment: I don't know enough about the half-life universe, so I'd rather not try to interpret the sources and give an answer. Sorry.

Comment: Here's another link that may be of interest: http://www.members.shaw.ca/halflifestory/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I believe the game takes place over a span of two days.

When Gordon goes outside past the rocket pit in chapter 8 (On a Rail), it is dark out:

[image: Rocket pit outside]

In the next chapter Gordon is captured by the assassins. I would guess he was out for multiple hours, which is why it's light outside when he escapes:

[image: Rocket pit outside]

Gordon then goes on to work through the facility some more, to the scientists, and then to Xen, all of which probably doesn't take more than a day.